# Binding javascript cases to html buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

i am in a school project and we are making a javascript game. The game consist of a field of 9 images, where you can use the commands "up" "down" "right" left" so move around. You enter the command in a text field and press enter. But we want the commands to be binded to html buttons.

This is what we got so far: http://jsfiddle.net/KAxrx/

```
<div id="gamebuttons">
    <button id="up" button onClick="">UP</button>
    <button id="down" button onClick="">DOWN</button>
    <button id="left" button onClick="">LEFT</button>
    <button id="right" button onClick="">RIGHT</button>
    </div>
```

It can also be seen live here: http://kaspermedk.dk/

We got no styling so far and some of it may be on danish.

But what we want is to connect the 4 commands to the 4 buttons we made. We are desperate so we hope someone can help us! :)

If you dont understand or you need more information please ask us :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without changing too much of your code, here's a way to do it

```js
function clickHandler(sender) {
    input.value = sender.id;

    playGame();
}
```

```html
<button id="up" onclick="clickHandler(this)">UP</button>
<button id="down" onclick="clickHandler(this)">DOWN</button>
<button id="left" onclick="clickHandler(this)">LEFT</button>
<button id="right" onclick="clickHandler(this)">RIGHT</button>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. We tried what you said, and it works (almost) sometimes it wont work, you can see it live here: http://kaspermedk.dk/ (scroll down a little)

Comment: update: Its only the down button there is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can add event listeners on your buttons.

I changed your code a little bit, <kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>.

I moved your switch to a separated function.

Take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I am providing a simple example of how to use `jQuery` to create ***left,right,top,bottom*** movements.

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vrga2/)

**jQuery**

```
var vertical = 0;
var horizontal = 0;
$('#game button').click(function(){
    var clk = $(this).attr('id');
    clk == "up"?vertical--:
    clk == "down"?vertical++:
    clk == "right"?horizontal++:
    horizontal--;
    $('#dot').css({'left':''+horizontal+'px','top':''+vertical+'px'});
});
```